# Spring Security - override default TokenEndpoint method (/oauth/token)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am planning to implement `oauth2 & JWT` in my new project. Apart from username, password & grant_type, I am having a few another fields to validate before granting the `access_token` and `refresh_token`. So I am planning to override the default `TokenEndpoint's postAccessToken` method's implementation. Would it be possible, if yes, what are all the things I should take care? And is it a right idea to override the default implementation? For example, below is TokenEndpoint's postAccessToken signature.

```
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> postAccessToken(Principal principal, @RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
....
}
```

Here before reaching the `postAccessToken` method only spring-security had constructed the `Principal` object.

My endpoint would look like this, where there is no `Principal` object(Not sure what issue this will introduce in future).

```
@PostMapping("/token")
public ResponseEntity token(@Valid @RequestBody LoginModel loginModel, @RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters) {
....
}
```

And few other things spring-security is taking care by itself, so if I override this /token endpoints what all things I should take care of?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using SpringBoot 3.0, the token path was changed from `/oauth/token` to `/oauth2/token` breaking existing consumers. All I had to do was the following:

```
    @Bean
    public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
        return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
                .tokenEndpoint("/oauth/token")
                .build();
    }
```

To change other attributes as well:

```
@Bean
public AuthorizationServerSettings authorizationServerSettings() {
    return AuthorizationServerSettings.builder()
        .issuer("https://example.com")
        .authorizationEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/authorize")
        .tokenEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/token")
        .tokenIntrospectionEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/introspect")
        .tokenRevocationEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/revoke")
        .jwkSetEndpoint("/oauth2/v1/jwks")
        .oidcUserInfoEndpoint("/connect/v1/userinfo")
        .oidcClientRegistrationEndpoint("/connect/v1/register")
        .build();
}
```

See [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-authorization-server/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-model.html#configuring-authorization-server-settings).

Answer (score 0):

```
Apart from username, password & grant_type, I am having a few another fields to validate before granting the access_token and refresh_token.
```

Since you have additional fields to be validated for password grant type, it is quite the not the password grant type any more. So it is not advisable to modify the default behavior by modifying the `TokenEndpoint`. What you can do is write a custom `TokenGranter`.

Have look at [ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/password/ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter.java) which is the implementation for password grant type. By basing that you can write a `CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter` like below :

```
public class CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter extends ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter {

private static final String GRANT_TYPE = "custom-password";

private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

public CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
        AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices, ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService, OAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory) {
    this(authenticationManager, tokenServices, clientDetailsService, requestFactory, GRANT_TYPE);
}

protected CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices,
        ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService, OAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory, String grantType) {
    super(tokenServices, clientDetailsService, requestFactory, grantType);
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
}

@Override
protected OAuth2Authentication getOAuth2Authentication(ClientDetails client, TokenRequest tokenRequest) {

    Map<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(tokenRequest.getRequestParameters());
    String username = parameters.get("username");
    String password = parameters.get("password");

    // You can use parameters.get to read your custom parameter fields

    ...

}
```

Important things to note here is `GRANT_TYPE` variable value and implementation of `getOAuth2Authentication`.

And finally you register your `CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter` implementation using the following Java configuration.

```
public TokenGranter tokenGranter() {

        ClientDetailsService clientDetails = clientDetailsService;
        AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices = tokenServices();
        AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices = authorizationCodeServices();
        OAuth2RequestFactory requestFactory = requestFactory();

        List<TokenGranter> tokenGranters = new ArrayList<TokenGranter>();

        tokenGranters.add(new AuthorizationCodeTokenGranter(tokenServices, authorizationCodeServices,
                clientDetails, requestFactory));
        tokenGranters.add(new RefreshTokenGranter(tokenServices, clientDetails, requestFactory));
        tokenGranters.add(new ImplicitTokenGranter(tokenServices, clientDetails, requestFactory));
        tokenGranters.add(new ClientCredentialsTokenGranter(tokenServices, clientDetails, requestFactory));
        tokenGranters.add(new ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter(authenticationManager, tokenServices,
                    clientDetails, requestFactory));
        tokenGranters.add(new CustomTokenGranter(authenticationManager, tokenServices(), clientDetailsService,
                requestFactory));
        // Register the CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter here
        tokenGranters.add(new CustomResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter(authenticationManager, tokenServices,
                    clientDetails, requestFactory));

        return new CompositeTokenGranter(tokenGranters);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {

    endpoints
            .tokenServices(tokenServices())
            .tokenStore(tokenStore())
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer())
            .authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
            .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler())
            .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
            .requestFactory(requestFactory())
            .tokenGranter(tokenGranter());
}
```

Finally you can send a POST request to `/oauth/token` with parameters `grant_type=custom-password&username=<Username>&password=<Password>&customFieldOne=1&customFieldTwo=2` and invoke your custom implementation.

Comment: Thanks Shazin, make sense. So if I want to modify the return type from `OAuth2AccessToken` to some `UserDefinedType`, would that be possible?